# Best way to bind a variable to object;

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects. For each object I need to set a schedule.

```
'node-schedule'
```

to reset the schedule I need it in a variable.

```
function setSchedule(ticket) {
  const date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

  const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function () {
    console.log('The world is going to end today.');
  });
}
```

how can I bind the object to his own schedule function? I mean, later I need to know which schedule I need to reset.

I would to it something like, but I think there is a better way?

```
const job[ticket.id] = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function () {
  console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could curry the function and save the curried function within the object: https://javascript.info/currying-partials

Answer (score 0):

The `job` variable will be available in the closure of the scheduled callback function, if referenced.

Consider, for instance, the following code, which is very similar to your own situation:

```js
const handle =
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("callback");
    clearInterval(handle);
  }, 100)
```

The callback fired once, then was cancelled by means of the `handle` variable that exists in an outer scope.

Comment: in my Obejct i have a Date inside. Now i need for each Object an own schedule Variable.
var1 = schedule.scheduleJob(obj[0].date) var2 = schedule.scheduleJob(obj[1].date). Now of course bit more dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i solve it this way

```js
function setSchedule(ticket) {
  if (ticket.blocked) {
    const date = new Date(ticket.blockedDate);
    scheduleJob[ticket._id] = schedule.scheduleJob(
      {
        date: date.getDate(),
        month: date.getMonth(),
        year: date.getFullYear(),
      },
      () => {
        console.log('Run' + ticket._id);
        scheduleJob[ticket._id].cancel();
        Ticket.updateOne(
          { _id: ticket._id },
          { blocked: false, blockedDate: null }
        )
          .then(() => {})
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    );
  }
  if (!ticket.blocked && scheduleJob[ticket._id]) {
    scheduleJob[ticket._id].cancel();
  }
}
```

What do you think? Is these a common way to use the id for array?